# Move and resize a test with an animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I want to move and resize a TextView from the center of the screen to the upper left corner with the default 16dp margin. I used the code:

```
val pos = convertDpToPixel(16.0f, context)
testNameTextView
    .animate()
    .scaleX(0.5f)
    .scaleY(0.5f)
    .x(pos)
    .y(pos)
```

It does not work because the final margin depends on the length of the text.
If I do not resize the view everything works fine.

I have also tried to do this:

```
testNameTextView
        .animate()
        .scaleX(0.5f)
        .scaleY(0.5f)
        .withEndAction {
            testNameTextView
                    .animate()
                    .x(pos)
                    .y(pos)
        }
```

but it did not make any difference. How can I resize and move the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
testNameTextView
        .animate()
        .scaleX(SCALE)
        .scaleY(SCALE)
        .x(posTestName - (testNameTextView.width - testNameTextView.width * SCALE) / 2 )
        .y(posTestName - (testNameTextView.height - testNameTextView.height * SCALE) / 2 )
```

So what happens is that the text is repositioned and then scaled keeping the center of the text fixed, so if you just do what I had done the left margin is incorrect because the text was shrunk.
You need to subtract the difference between half the width of the text before the scale and half the width of the text after the scaling.

PS
During the animation the translation and the resizing are done at the same time but the effect is the same as if the text was first translated and then scaled keeping the center of the text fixed